# Symbols taking very, very long time to load when hosting ASP.NET app in IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis, performance, symbols

I'm hosting my project using IIS, running from Visual Studio.

Whenever I recompile, on the first run it takes several minutes (on a not awful machine) to load all the symbols.

Please see http://joshz.com/so/symbols.html for a list of the symbols that are loaded. At the bottom there is a `ThreadAbortException`, I'm not sure if this is playing a role.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated; it's slowing my day down enormously!

As a note: the project has never run quickly since I joined the company and started working with it.

**Edit:**

My symbols options window looks rather a lot like this:

[alt text http://joshz.com/so/symbols.png](http://joshz.com/so/symbols.png)

Is this wrong?

Comment: How did you configure the symbols location in VS?

Comment: @lkaso - great question, my symbols screen in VS looks rather a lot like this: http://joshz.com/so/symbols.png

Answer (score 0):

Clear/Delete all of your break points and check.